# Updating a list of messages in a RecyclerView using LiveData without reposting the whole list

Tags: android, android-livedata

While connected to a bluetooth device I receive a big number of measurements from it which I wish to display on screen without reposting the whole list.

To do this I use a ViewModel like so:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val logic: MainLogic = MainLogic(this, AppDispatchers)
    val messageList = mutableListOf<String>()
    val newMessage = SingleLiveEvent<String>()
    val clearMessages = SingleLiveEvent<Unit>()

    fun addMessage(message: String) {
        messageList.add(message)
        newMessage.postValue(message)
    }

    override fun clearMessages() {
        messageList.clear()
        clearMessages.postValue(null)
    }
}
```

this holds the complete list in the view model, and is supposed to only send the updates to the main screen

I also use SingleLiveEvent as shown on :

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java

My main activity looks like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var vm: MainViewModel
    private lateinit var adapter: MessageAdapter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        vm = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        adapter = MessageAdapter(vm.messageList)
        messages.adapter = adapter
        setUpObservers()
    }

    private fun setUpObservers() {
        vm.clearMessages.observe(this, Observer {
            adapter.clear()
        })
        vm.newMessage.observe(this, Observer {
            adapter.addMessage(it)
        })
    }
}
```

When the message flow is slow this works correctly, the adapter only adds new messages and when the message to clear is received it is cleared.

Unfortunately when the message flow is fast a lot of messages are lost, when I rotate the screen (thus the adapter is recreated from `vm.messageList`) all the messages are shown so I haven't lost anything

Is there a way to show the list correctly without posting the whole list all over again?

Comment: I'd rather recommend posting the whole list then diffing on the other side (ListAdapter). There is no reason to use SingleLiveEvent here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you are using `SingleLiveEvent` which holds one event at a time. So if you are calling `newMessage.postValue(message)` a few times in a row, new message overwrites the previous one, which was not delivered yet.

It's definitely possible to update the list without reloading the whole dataset. Assuming you are using `RecylerView` and calling [`notifyItemInserted`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted(int)) properly, you just need to pass all the new messages to your activity. There are quite a few ways to do so, e.g. use rxJava or [kotlin coroutines channels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html). Both of them provide a way to create a stream to post messages to, which you can observe. They will also buffer messages if you are consuming them slower than they are being produced.

Comment: That's a great idea, I didn't even think of using rxjava subjects to retain the data when it is not yet processed. thanks that's probably gonna do the job

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround is to store this new messages in local db (like Room) with previous messages and update list by timeout (for example every 2 seconds) and/or by critical messages difference (amount messages in db minus amount of messages in adapter > some threshold).

To speed up messages download from database you can use Page library from Android Architecture components.
See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList and 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil

Hope it'll help

Comment: That is a decent solution, unfortunately parsing the events is time critical, and I cannot waste the time that it will take to save it to a database (even an in-memory one) and then perform the whole paging thing. Right now I just use a list to check what the bluetooth device sends me, but later on I will have to interpret the commands and perform the actions as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed the question again after some time, the way I finally did it is by keeping the adapter in the view model so the code becomes

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    vm = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    messages.adapter = vm.messageAdapter
    setUpObservers()
}
```

then in the view model

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val logic: MainLogic = MainLogic(this, AppDispatchers)
    val messageAdapter = MessageAdapter()

    fun addMessage(message: String) {
        messageAdapter.add(message)
    }

    override fun clearMessages() {
        messageAdapter.clear()
    }
}
```

When the adapter is attached, all notify events trigger (because it can find the RecyclerView) and when it is not it just does nothing.

The important thing seems to be to not add any sort of context related variable to the adapter.

On the only method that it is truely needed (onCreateViewHolder) you can get it from parent.context which only exists when the adapter is attached